# remote printer is only printing when using eth0 and not wlan0

Tags: linux, printing, cups

I have a weird scenario where my network printer (local network) only prints when I connect my laptop with ethernet (using eth0). When the laptop uses wifi (wlan0) the job ends up in the queue but is not send to the printer. When I look at localhost:631 I can see the printer and the new printjob. I can also 'release' the job for printing, but it returns to being 'on hold'. I can also ping the printer. As soon as I plug the network cable, the job prints.

Comment: Most likely your cable and your wireless network use different ip ranges. Apparently the routing works on OS level, but not inside your cups server. But there is little we can say without you posting your network topology and the relevant cups configuration.

Comment: Both are in the same ip range. the laptop gets 192.168.0.43 when plugged via ethernet and e.g. 192.168.0.157 when connecting via wlan0. What is the "relevant cups configuration"?

Comment: Hm, what connection do you use to access the printer? Have a try faking exactly the same connection manually: use the "telnet" cli utility to make a connection to the printer and from the laptop using Wifi and try to connect to the printers network port that is configured in the connection part of the cups configuration. What type of printer is it, by the way?